# findParentRow() in zend 1.12

Tags: zend-framework, one-to-many

i'm new in zend framework and i've an issue to get the author from a book with a relation:
Fatal error: Call to a member function findParentRow() on a non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\quickstart\application\controllers\BookController.php on line 14

i put my classes but the goal is to do an app with a 1,n relation between author and book

```
    <?php

class Application_Model_BookMapper
{
    protected $_dbTable;

    public function setDbTable($dbTable)
    {
        if (is_string($dbTable)) {
            $dbTable = new $dbTable();
        }
        if (!$dbTable instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Abstract) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid table data gateway provided');
        }
        $this->_dbTable = $dbTable;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDbTable()
    {
        if (null === $this->_dbTable) {
            $this->setDbTable('Application_Model_DbTable_Book');
        }
        return $this->_dbTable;
    }

    public function find($id, Application_Model_Book $book)
    {
        $result = $this->getDbTable()->find($id);
        if (0 == count($result)) {
            return;
        }
        $row = $result->current();
        $book->setId($row->id)
                  ->setTitle($row->title)
                  ->setAuteur($row->auteur_id);
    }

    public function fetchAll()
    {
        $resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll();
        $entries   = array();
        foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
            $entry = new Application_Model_book();
            $entry->setId($row->id)
                  ->setTitle($row->title)
                  ->setAuteur($row->auteur_id);
            $entries[] = $entry;
        }
        return $entries;
    }

    public function findAuteur($id, Application_Model_Book $book)
    {
        $result = $this->getDbTable()->find($id);
        if (0 == count($result)) {
            return;
        }
        $row = $result->current();

        //hydratation de l'objet book
        $book->setId($row->id)
        ->setTitle($row->title);

        //Utilisation d'une methode pour récupérer l'auteur u livre
        $rowAuteur=$row->findParentRow('Auteur');      
        $auteur= new Application_Model_Auteur();
        //hydratation de l'objet Auteur
        $auteur->setId($rowAuteur->id)
        ->setName($rowAuteur->name);

        //Attacher l'auteur à l'article
        $book->setAuteur($auteur);
        return $book;
    }

}

<?php

class Application_Model_AuteurMapper
{
    protected $_dbTable;

    public function setDbTable($dbTable)
    {
        if (is_string($dbTable)) {
            $dbTable = new $dbTable();
        }
        if (!$dbTable instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Abstract) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid table data gateway provided');
        }
        $this->_dbTable = $dbTable;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDbTable()
    {
        if (null === $this->_dbTable) {
            $this->setDbTable('Application_Model_DbTable_Auteur');
        }
        return $this->_dbTable;
    }

    public function find($id, Application_Model_Auteur $auteur)
    {
        $result = $this->getDbTable()->find($id);
        if (0 == count($result)) {
            return;
        }
        $row = $result->current();
        $auteur->setId($row->id)
                  ->setName($row->name);
    }

    public function fetchAll()
    {
        $resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll();
        $entries   = array();
        foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
            $entry = new Application_Model_Auteur();
            $entry->setId($row->id)
                  ->setName($row->name);
            $entries[] = $entry;
        }
        return $entries;
    }

}

<?php

class Application_Model_DbTable_Book extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected $_name = 'book';
    protected $_referenceMap    = array(
        'Auteur' => array(
            'columns'           => 'auteur_id',
            'refTableClass'     => 'Application_Model_DbTable_Auteur',
            'refColumns'        => 'id'
        )
    );

}


<?php

class Application_Model_DbTable_Auteur extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected $_name = 'auteur';
    protected $_dependentTables = array('Application_Model_DbTable_Book');

}



<?php

class Application_Model_Book extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract
{
    protected $_id;
    protected $_title;
    protected $_auteur;

    public function __construct(array $options = null)
    {
        if (is_array($options)) {
            $this->setOptions($options);
        }
    }

    public function __set($title, $value)
    {
        $method = 'set' . $title;
        if (('mapper' == $title) || !method_exists($this, $method)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid guestbook property');
        }
        $this->$method($value);
    }

    public function __get($title)
    {
        $method = 'get' . $title;
        if (('mapper' == $title) || !method_exists($this, $method)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid guestbook property');
        }
        return $this->$method();
    }

    public function setOptions(array $options)
    {
        $methods = get_class_methods($this);
        foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
            $method = 'set' . ucfirst($key);
            if (in_array($method, $methods)) {
                $this->$method($value);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function settitle($title)
    {
        $this->_title = (string) $title;
        return $this;
    }

    public function gettitle()
    {
        return $this->_title;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->_id = (int) $id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->_id;
    }

    public function setAuteur($auteur)
    {
        $this->_auteur = (string) $auteur;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getAuteur()
    {
        //if (!$this->_auteur) {
            //$this->_auteur = $this->findParentRow('Application_Model_DbTable_Book');
        //}
        return $this->_auteur;
    }
}

<?php

class Application_Model_Auteur extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract
{
    protected $_id;
    protected $_name;

    public function __construct(array $options = null)
    {
        if (is_array($options)) {
            $this->setOptions($options);
        }
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $method = 'set' . $name;
        if (('mapper' == $name) || !method_exists($this, $method)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid guestbook property');
        }
        $this->$method($value);
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        $method = 'get' . $name;
        if (('mapper' == $name) || !method_exists($this, $method)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid guestbook property');
        }
        return $this->$method();
    }

    public function setOptions(array $options)
    {
        $methods = get_class_methods($this);
        foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
            $method = 'set' . ucfirst($key);
            if (in_array($method, $methods)) {
                $this->$method($value);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->_name = (string) $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->_name;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->_id = (int) $id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->_id;
    }

    public function getBooks(){

    }
}
```

I'm using yii framework before and the difference is really big.
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It'd be easier if you put code from your bookcontroller here. But what Zend is saying is that you don't have instance of Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract object(you don't have any object at all). If you want to use method findParentRow(), you have to be sure that you have this object. So first check type of your variable.

Answer (score 0):

i tested if it's a correct type (Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract) and it':

```
$book = new Application_Model_BookMapper();

    //$name = $t->findParentRow('Application_Model_DbTable_Book');
    $this->view->entries = $book->fetchAll();//findAuteur(1,new Application_Model_Book());
    foreach ($this->view->entries as $b){
        echo gettype($b)."&&class=".get_class($b);
        if ($b instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract) {
            echo 'okkk';
        }
        //$name = $b->findParentRow('Application_Model_DbTable_Auteur');//findDependentRowset
    }
```